# Where is the wordpress folder in XAMPP?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I have installed XAMPP on my mac and recently downloaded and installed Bitnami-Wordpress. It all works fine but I just cant find the Wordpress folder. I can open wordpress in my browser with `http://localhost/wordpress`. So I thought there must be a wordpress folder in htdocs. But I just cant find it in htdocs or any subfolders. I want to access the themes folder. Maybe I am searching in the wrong place? I am really lost here. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Go to the folder where you install XAMPP and start looking til you find a folder that has a file called `wp-config.php`, or just search that file in your computer

Comment: I do not find this file either. I have installed the XAMPP folder in Applications. In the XAMPP folder there is the `htdocs` folder. And in the `htdocs`folder there is a `XAMPP`folder again. If I go to my browser and open `http://localhost/xampp/` that "welcome to XAMPP"-page appears, which is the `index.php` within the `XAMPP`folder (`applications/XAMPP/htdocs/XAMPP/index.php`). So far so good. I also can open `http://localhost/wordpress/`, can log in and change the content… So my conclusion was there must be a wordpress folder in `htdocs`with a `index.php`or a `index.html` in it?

Comment: I just tried to access it  via `file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/index.php`, which does not work. So it seems I am searching in the wrong place for that folder.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem before.

WordPress is considered an app so it is usually in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs

It can vary but that should be a good lead.

And yes, I don't know why finding it is not more trivial either. I found it challenging also.

Comment: how to open it in url

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but I was looking for the location.

On macOS Wordpress install is located in:

XAMPP.app/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress